# What to do when raspbmc loses mounted usb hard drive?

Tags: usb, raspbmc, mount

I have a raspberry pi with raspbmc installed on. It used to run very stable, no issues at all.
Since I have installed BitTorrent Sync, that has changed however.

When I restart BitTorrent Sync or when the pi has been running, the usb drive gets disconnected.

Running df gets:
df: `/media/Extern station': Transport endpoint is not connected

The only solution for now seems to be: restarting the pi.

Any ideas what could be going on, how I could solve this without restarting the pi?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally the only solution is to reconnect the drive. If it's bus powered plug it in through a powered hub. I suspect that your drive, and by extension the USB bus is getting hammered by the checksum stage of BT. This is causing it to drop out. I'm not sure you can disable that with BT Sync though. It seems there's a `disk_low_priority` [setting](http://btsync.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/BitTorrentSyncUserGuide.pdf) though that you can set to `true` that may help. Setting the `rate_limit_local_peers` to a value less than 5MB/s may help as well as this will also lower disk load.

Comment: Thanks, I have enforced those settings. Upon restarting btsync the disk went down, so it's rebooting too. I'll keep you updated if this resolves it.